# Format my output JSON more Readable

Tags: php, json, web

This is my current PHP code

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $post = new Post();
        $post->setId($row['post_id']); 
        $post->setBody($row['post_body']); 
        $post->setImage($row['post_imgurl']);
        $post->setStamp($row['post_stamp']);
        $postList[]  = $post;
    }
    return array('post'=> $postList);
}
```

and this is its [output JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwkz1.png). 
How can i make my JSON more readable like below and remove `/` the character?

More readable output:

[image: ExtraCharacterandJSONFormat]

Comment: what do you mean by "readable"?

Comment: More readable where?  What's the *real* issue here?  The `/` needs to be escaped in a JSON string, that's how it works (see: http://json.org/)

Comment: If you don't escape the backslashes, it won't be valid JSON. What does it look like when you actually output the image value?

Comment: The `/` doesn't need to be escaped (``\`` does), but it does no harm if you do. PHP  escapes them so that having `</script>` in a string literal will become `<\/script>` and thus won't terminate a script block if you use the JSON as JavaScript in HTML.

Comment: thank you guys. this is the current output of my JSON http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue4Aa.png and i want to make it http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwkz1.png :)

Comment: @Toshi: So, you just want to indent it?  How are you making your JSON?  You can try `json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, you got it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want readable JSON, then read it in a tool designed to present JSON for reading (such as the Chrome JSONView extension). Don't try to munge raw data into particular patterns.

That said, you *can* persuade PHP to munge the data in that fashion with:

```
json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Please, take a look at the $options param of the json_encode function, I am sure, it solves your problem.

Comment: In particular, `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`